# View SQL - subtraction of date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the following view

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.vw_IssueDates AS 
SELECT UserId,
       IssueDate

FROM users 
WHERE IssueDATE <= CONVERT(DATE,  '2015-01-20')
GO
SELECT * FROM dbo.vw_IssueDates
```

I am trying list user that have outstanding fines for over 30 days, I know it will involve GETDATE dynamically (so todays date) and subtract 30 but not sure where to begin?

Comment: Is `IssueDate` the issue date of the fine?  How do you know if it is outstanding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `DATEADD(day,-30,GETDATE())`

```
SELECT UserId, IssueDate
FROM users
WHERE IssueDate >= DATEADD(day,-30,GETDATE())
```

Also if you want it in a column how many days over due..

```
SELECT UserId, IssueDate, DATEDIFF(day,IssueDate,GETDATE()) AS DaysOverDue
FROM users
WHERE IssueDate >= DATEADD(day,-30,GETDATE())
```

Comment: Forgive me if I'm wrong, but I think Vlad11 wants outstanding fines for over 30 days. So I would think that would mean fines that were issued over 30 days ago. So in your where clause I think it should be less than not greater than.

Comment: Possibly, unless IssueDate is the date of whatever was issued, a book for example.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to solve this issue would be using datediff function. Here is what you can do:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.vw_IssueDates AS 
SELECT UserId,
       IssueDate
FROM users 
WHERE DATEDIFF(day,IssueDATE,getdate()) > 30
GO
SELECT * FROM dbo.vw_IssueDates
```